# Powershell HasChildNodes is true for text?

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

When working with XML objects in Powershell should the HasChildNodes return true if the element just has text data and not another element? Is there not a way to identify elements that do not have any actual elements under them?

Given the example below I was hoping that the element Parameter_Section would return true for having children, but I would not expect the elements inside to also return true if they had data. For example, SCM_Included, SendToApp, and WF_Start all return true because they have text. The definition says "Gets a value indicating whether this node has any child nodes". Does that mean text or data is considered a child node?

I'm parsing a bunch of InfoPath XML files and I was hoping to be able to ignore the parent elements like Parameter_Section that only serve to organize (InfoPath calls them "sections") the child elements that actually store data (which are fields in InfoPath).

```
function ReadAllNodes ($node) {
foreach ($childnode in $node.ChildNodes)
{
    [string] $path = Get-XPath($childnode)
    [string] $nt = $childnode.NodeType
    [string] $hc = $childnode.HasChildNodes
    [string] $name = $childnode.Name
    [string] $val = $childnode.Value
    [string] $txt = $childnode.'#text'

    Write-Host (“Name={0}, path={1}, type={2}, hc={3}, val={4}, txt={5}” -f $name, $path, $nt, $hc,$val,$txt)
}

foreach ($cn in $childnode) {
    ReadAllNodes $cn
    }
}

$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myFields>
    <Parameter_Section>
        <Approval_Mode />
        <SCM_Included>n</SCM_Included>
        <ApprovalCompleteDateTime />
        <ApprovalCompleteDateStr />
        <SendToApp>No</SendToApp>
        <WF_Start>0</WF_Start>
        <QuoteAttachCount>0</QuoteAttachCount>
        <TestEmail />
        <TestMessage />
        <IsCurrentUserRequestor>true</IsCurrentUserRequestor>
        <CanCurrentUserApprove>Approve</CanCurrentUserApprove>
    </Parameter_Section>
</myFields>
"@

$content = New-Object -TypeName XML
$content.LoadXml($Xml)
[System.Xml.XmlElement] $root = $content.get_DocumentElement()

ReadAllNodes $root





    Name=Parameter_Section, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=
Name=Approval_Mode, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/Approval_Mode, type=Element, hc=False, val=, txt=
Name=SCM_Included, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/SCM_Included, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=n
Name=ApprovalCompleteDateTime, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/ApprovalCompleteDateTime, type=Element, hc=False, val=, txt=
Name=ApprovalCompleteDateStr, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/ApprovalCompleteDateStr, type=Element, hc=False, val=, txt=
Name=SendToApp, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/SendToApp, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=No
Name=WF_Start, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/WF_Start, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=0
Name=QuoteAttachCount, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/QuoteAttachCount, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=0
Name=TestEmail, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/TestEmail, type=Element, hc=False, val=, txt=
Name=TestMessage, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/TestMessage, type=Element, hc=False, val=, txt=
Name=IsCurrentUserRequestor, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/IsCurrentUserRequestor, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=true
Name=CanCurrentUserApprove, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/CanCurrentUserApprove, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=Approve
Name=#text, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/CanCurrentUserApprove/#text, type=Text, hc=False, val=Approve, txt=
```

Comment: `.NET` is truthy.  If an item is not `null`, `string.EmptyString` or `0`, then it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: It's not the source of the problem, but thanks for pointing out the "truthiness" of _any_ nonempty string _in PowerShell_ - even if it happens to contain the _literal_ string `False`. However, note that that's not a _.NET_ feature per se; for instance, this loose type of to-Boolean conversion doesn't work in C# at all, for instance.

Comment: @mklement0 It applies to more than just strings and IIRC the same applies to C# (haven't had to write any recently).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Yes, _in PowerShell_ to-Boolean coercion applies to _any_ data type, but the point is that that logic is up to each .NET-based _language_, not .NET (the CLR) itself. And, no, C# does _not_ support coercing arbitrary types to `[bool]` _implicitly_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean text or data is considered a child node?

Yes, indeed it does.

The string "Approve" inside the `<CanCurrentUserApprove>` node is itself an `XmlText` node. And as you might expect, you can access a text node through the `ChildNodes` property.

Try the following example:

```
$content.SelectNodes('//CanCurrentUserApprove')[0].ChildNodes[0]
```

Comment: I think I see one reason this confused me so much. My loop only shows the text node for the last one on the list. Had the loop showed a text node for all the other elements it might have been more obvious. I need to see if I can fix that loop.  `Name=CanCurrentUserApprove, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/CanCurrentUserApprove, type=Element, hc=True, val=, txt=Approve
Name=#text, path=/myFields/Parameter_Section/CanCurrentUserApprove/#text, type=Text, hc=False, val=Approve, txt=`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to test for child *elements*, not *nodes*, because text seemingly contained inside an element is indeed a child *node* of type `Text`.

While you *could* inspect the XML elements individually<sup>[1]</sup>
, it is **easier to use an XPath query via the [`Select-Xml` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml)**:

The following finds all elements that have no child *elements* and returns those whose `.InnerText` property is nonempty, implying that they "contain text":

```
Select-Xml -XPath '//*[count(*)=0] and text()' -Content $Xml |
  Select-Object Node, @{ n='Text'; e={ $_.Node.InnerText } }
```

With your sample XML, the above yields:

```
Node                   Text
----                   ----
SCM_Included           n
SendToApp              No
WF_Start               0
QuoteAttachCount       0
IsCurrentUserRequestor true
CanCurrentUserApprove  Approve
```

- `//*[count(*)=0]` matches only elements of any name (`*`) that have no *element* children (`count(*)=0`), anywhere in the document `//`.
- `and text()` limits the matches to those elements whose `.InnerText` property value is non-empty.

  - Note: An element node without *element* child nodes that has a nonempty `.InnerText` property need not always have just a *single* child node of type `Text`; there may be *multiple* child nodes comprising any mix of types `Text`, `EntityReference`, and `CDATASection` that `.InnerText` joins to form a single string.
- The `Select-Object` call constructs custom objects, each of whose `.Node` property contains a matched XML element, and whose `.Text` property contains that element's `.InnerText` value.

---

[1] It's actually nontrivial to **robustly check a given element for the *absence* of *element* children**, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out; in PSv3+, you can use the following:

```
$elem.ChildNodes.NodeType -notcontains 'Element'
```

To additionally check if such an element "contains text" (has non-element child nodes that [combine to] have a nonempty textual representation):

```
$elem.ChildNodes.NodeType -notcontains 'Element' -and $elem.InnerText -ne ''
```

<sup>You can omit `-ne ''` at the end, because any nonempty string in PowerShell is "truthy".</sup>